# Finding overall Document Score in Document Object

Tags: cloud-document-ai

In the Document Object, is there some field that lists the overall confidence score of the entire document? I am using a custom document processor and calling it from the Python API, so I can see the confidence levels for each of the labels in my schema under the entities field. The only mentions of confidence I see are for specific items like detectedLanguage rather than for the document as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a field in the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) object for overall confidence, you will need to access it from the individual fields that you want to pay attention to. Such as `detectedLanguage`, `Entity`, `FormField`.